# how to remove a tag having value &#160;

Tags: xml, xslt, tags, space

Input is :

```
<p>&#160;</p>
```

Output is :

```
<p></p>
```

I want to delete the empty tag in output file as `&#160;` is nbsp and in output it is getting converted into space but I don't want this tag with space.

Input is :

```
<div>
    <title>Operational Commands</title>
    <p>show ip nat filtershow ip nat interfaceshow ip nat interface-statistics</p>
<div>
    <title>Release Information</title>
    <p>Command introduced in Viptela Software Release 18.3.​</p>
</div>
<div>
    <title>Additional Information</title>
    <p>See the Configuring Transport-Side NAT article for your software release.</p>
    <p> </p>
</div>
```

and my xslt code is :

```
<xsl:variable name='list' select='//div'/>

<xsl:template match='/'>

        <xsl:for-each select='$list'>
            <xsl:element name='section'>
                <xsl:apply-templates select='*[not(name(.)="div")]'/>

            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

Output is:

```
 <section>
        <title>Operational Commands</title>
        <p>show ip nat filtershow ip nat interfaceshow ip nat interface-statistics</p>
    </section><section>
        <title>Release Information</title>
        <p>Command introduced in Viptela Software Release 18.3.​</p>
    </section><section>
        <title>Additional Information</title>
        <p>See the Configuring Transport-Side NAT article for your software release.</p>
        <p> </p>
    </section>
```

In last section `<p>` tag is having space which is considered as empty tag then I need to remove this empty tag. How can I remove this?

Comment: here  input is :<p> nbsp in ASCII form </p> i. e &# 160 ;

Comment: If you have any existing XSLT that "converts" that non-breaking space into a normal space then you should show us that code. It is not clear whether you want to fix some particular XSLT code or whether you want to write XSLT to remove any `<p>&#160;</p>` elements from any input.

Comment: I have written my code below ..

Comment: Please edit your question to provide any details there and not as an answer. Also consider to show us minimal but complete samples and information to allow us to reproduce the problem. The part of the XSLT you have shown in your "answer" doesn't create any `p` elements at all. Nor does it convert characters like non-breaking spaces into spaces.

Comment: Okay...then what I need to do to remove the empty <p> tag?

Answer (score 1):

First, an element that contains a non-breaking space is not empty. And the non-breaking space is not "getting converted into space" in the output, unless you have  instructed the stylesheet to convert it.

Now, to remove the `<p>&#160;</p>` element, you could add an empty template matching it:

```
<xsl:template match="p[.='&#160;']"/>
```

If you want, you can make a more generic template that removes all empty and whitespace-only `p` elements:

```
<xsl:template match="p[not(normalize-space(translate(., '&#160;', ' ')))]"/>
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: Actually I want to remove all the empty tags that are present in xml

Comment: I have two scenarios in my xml
1. <p>&#160;</p>
2. <dl></dl>
when I am applying

Comment: To remove all empty elements, you can use `<xsl:template match="*[...]"/>`. To remove some empty elements, you can use `<xsl:template match="(p|dl)[...]"/>`.

Comment: Actually I have 2 scenarios in my code.                                                               1. <p>&#160;</p> and 2. <dl></dl>                    when I was applying this code  -> <xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space(translate(., '&#160;', ' ')))]"/>it will remove the empty<p>tag from the output but not the empty <dl > tag. I need a statement which can remove all the empty tags.Also, I have used <xsl:template match="*[not(node())]" /> for empty <dl> tag .but only one statement works at a time...Please help me to provide the code which would be generic and removes all empty tags.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see your XSLT code so I cannot debug it even if I wanted to. If necessary, post a new question and make sure to include a [mcve].